# jQuery - Displaying number of collection of elements based on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to display a number of paragraphs based on user selection in a dropdown.

The paragraphs are id'd like this:

```
<p id="addActor1">
<p id="addActor2">
... etc
```

Here's the jQuery I **tried**, but doesn't work (as is, it displays all of the paragraphs):

```
$('#ddlSelectNumActorsToAdd').change(function () {
    var num = $(this).val();

    for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        $.each($('#addActors p'), function (i, value) {
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
        });
    }
});
```

I *know* the above is wrong, I'm just not sure how exactly to implement the $.each() function properly to do what I need to do...

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eventide/quyRW/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `:lt` selector, and shorten it to just:

```
$('#ddlSelectNumActorsToAdd').change(function () {
    $('#addActors p').hide().filter(':lt(' + $(this).val() + ')').fadeIn(200);
});
```

Here we're hiding all of the `p`'s to start off with, then choosing only those whose position is `:lt` the selected value (`$(this).val()`), and `fadeIn`'ing them.

You can see this now working here; http://jsfiddle.net/quyRW/3/

Alternatively you can use `slice()`, which will probably turn out to be microscopically faster;

```
$('#ddlSelectNumActorsToAdd').change(function () {
    $('#addActors p').hide().slice(0, $(this).val()).fadeIn(200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/quyRW/8/

---

Note also that, in the majority of cases, you don't need to use `each()`; jQuery will perform the operation on each matched element. For example, instead of;

```
$('#addActors p').each(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

... you can just have;

```
$('#addActors p').hide();
```

Comment: I like the single-line simplicity of your answer. This works as needed. Thanks, Matt!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addActors p').each(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});


$('#ddlSelectNumActorsToAdd').change(function () {
    var num = $(this).val();
    $('#addActors p').each(function (i, actor) {
        $(this).hide();
        if (i < num) {
            $(actor).fadeIn(200);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/quyRW/5/